# Telerik mvc grid expand only selected row client template

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have two grids one for customer and another grid in a client template which shows the customer profile inline.On Expanding the row of the parent grid,i am able to get the unique id and load profile based on the customer id and this displays well the profile in the client template grid under that selected row.

However,if i select another second item in the parent window,the details of that particular id are not shown in that second row client template view but they are displayed in the first Grid of the first row with the correct details of the second unique id.According to me it seems that the grid did a switching but instead of displaying those results on the second row Grid,it displayed on the first row section.How can i be able to ensure that for every selected row,it displays its respective results under the same row but not displaying the results on the first row.

If i o ahead and i select another item lets say item 4,the inline details will take changes in the first grid but that particular row grid will not display results.Below is the structure of my grid.

I am following this example to display my records http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/html5-dashboard-sample-app/Home/ProductsAndOrders

Below is my grids.

```
                <script>
              function onDetailsDatabound() {
                    var firstRow = this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first();
                    var model = this.dataItem(firstRow);
                    if (!model.isNew()) {
                        this.expandRow(firstRow);
                    }
                }
                function onCustomerInfoDisplay(e) {
                    if (!e.model.isNew()) {

                        e.container.find("[name=CustomerId]").data("kendoDropDownList").enable(false);
                    } else {
                        e.container.find("td.k-hierarchy-cell").css({ visibility: "hidden" });
                    }
                }
                function onDataBound(e) {
                    var firstRow = this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first();
                    var model = this.dataItem(firstRow);
                    if (!model.isNew()) {

                        this.expandRow(firstRow);
                    }

                }

                function OnDetailExpand(e) {

                    $(e.detailRow).find('.t-grid').data().tGrid.ajaxRequest();
                }
            </script>


            <div>
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.CustomerDetails).Name("Customers")
                        .DataSource(x => x.Ajax().PageSize(100).Read("LoadCustomers", "Customer").Model(d =>
                    {
                        d.Id(e => e.CustomerId);
                        d.Field(a => a.CustomerId).Editable(false);

                    }).ServerOperation(false))

                    .Selectable()
                    .Pageable(s => s.Refresh(true))
                    .Navigatable()



                    .Columns(d =>
                    {

                        d.Bound(c => c.CustomerId).Title("CustomerData");

                        d.Bound(s => s.FirstName).Title("FirstName");
                        d.Bound(s => s.LastName).Title("LastName").Visible(true);
                        d.Bound(s => s.Email).Title("Email Address").Visible(false);


                    })
                    .BindTo(Model.Customers)
                            .Pageable(c => c.Enabled(true).PageSizes(true)).ClientDetailTemplateId("clientTemplate").Events(a => a.DataBound("onDataBound").DetailExpand("OnDetailExpand"))







                )




            </div>

            <script id="clientTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">


              @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.CustomerBio).Name("records").Columns(a =>
                        {
                            a.Bound(s => s.KinName);
                             a.Bound(s => s.KinIdNumber);
                              a.Bound(s => s.KinPostalCode);
                               a.Bound(s => s.KinCity);
                        }).DataSource(a => a.Ajax().Model(b => b.Id(x => x.ProfileId)).Read("GetCustomerBioByCustomerId", "Customer",new {CustomerId="#=CustomerId#"})).Events(a => a.DataBound("onDetailsDatabound").Edit("onCustomerInfoDisplay")).ToClientTemplate())


            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by ensuring the Client template Grid Name is unique.The issue was the Grids had same name when  displaying the results.Here is the updated client template Grid name which i am parsing the unique id in the name field

```
   <script id="clientTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">


          @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.CustomerBio).Name("CustomerDisplay#=CustomerId#"").Columns(a =>
                    {
                        a.Bound(s => s.KinName);
                         a.Bound(s => s.KinIdNumber);
                          a.Bound(s => s.KinPostalCode);
                           a.Bound(s => s.KinCity);
                    }).DataSource(a => a.Ajax().Model(b => b.Id(x => x.ProfileId)).Read("GetCustomerBioByCustomerId", "Customer",new {CustomerId="#=CustomerId#"})).Events(a => a.DataBound("onDetailsDatabound").Edit("onCustomerInfoDisplay")).ToClientTemplate())


        </script>
```

In this case,every time i expand the grid row will assign to the grid the grid name plus its unique id hence making sure no grids are of the same name .The problem was because all the child grids had the same name hence displaying results on the first grid